# Can't seek video time on VLC MediaPlayer in android programmatically

Tags: android, vlc, libvlc, vlc-android

Integrated VLC media player in android application.When for the first time the activity get opened ,trying to seek the video time for 10 sec. The code is as below

```
        var mediaObject = Media(mLibVLC, videoUrl)
        videoPlayer.media =  mediaObject         
        videoPlayer.play()         
        videoPlayer.setTime(10000,true)
        debug("===>isSeekable "+videoPlayer.isSeekable)
        

        Logcat ===>isSeekable false
```

Now i can see from the log cat that the video is not seekable, so the seeking is not working for the initial video, but when play the next video, isSeekable is true from next time onward.

How to change this behaviour.

Note: implementation "org.videolan.android:libvlc-all:3.4.2" using this version of vlc

Comment: some videos are not seekable. Can you seek in vlc for android?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the video isn't yet playing.
Either set it playing, allowing a fraction of a second for it to fire-up and then `seek` or use the `Media` option and then use a form of `Media.add_option('start-time='+restart_time)`.

Seek only works if the video is already playing.

Edit:
Any pause should be after the `videoPlayer.play()`

`restart_time` would be a string in seconds e.g. start_time=10.5
See the vlc command line `--start-time=83.4`
https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Jump_to_a_certain_time/

Also as `mfkl` points out some media isn't seekable
Note: I work in python so you may have to translate to whatever Android is using, I've no clue.

Comment: I have added a delay to check the isSeekable, when Activity launched first time and the video is also first video returning false always. But i will try this option

Comment: Tried to set the option, that is not working for me.

Comment: @BiplabDe i've edited my answer for clarity

Comment: This is not working for me. But appreciate your help @Rolf